# Wait for an element not being covered in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm getting an error:

```
imed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element:

<a class="icon" href="#home/">...</a>

is being covered by another element:
```

I don't want to use `{force:true}` on click action. I just want to wait for that element being visible (not covered anymore) and then click on it.

I tried
`cy.get("a")should("be.visible")` but it seems it doesn't fits this case.

Comment: try cy.wait() and see

Comment: Could you provide a sample code or something that could repro this issue?

Comment: Posting a HTML code of the said element would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an idea about what element is blocking the element you are trying to click, it may be worth trying

```
cy.get(blockingElementSelector).should("not.be.visible")
```

Alternatively if the element goes away entirely you could try

```
cy.get(blockingElementSelector).should("not.exist")
```