# Cypress assertion - element is actionable / not covered

Tags: javascript, cypress, wait, assertion

I would like to expand on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64540762/wait-for-an-element-not-being-covered-in-cypress) as I have a similar question:

I want to `cy.get('#lead_name').type('foo')` but it is covered by this element with opacity 0.9 while the form is loading:

```html
<div class="blockUI blockOverlay" style="z-index: 1000; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 665px; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.9; cursor: wait; position: absolute;"></div>
```

When I start with the assertion

```js
cy.get('#lead_name').should('be.visible)
```

it passes the assertion (maybe because of the opacity?) but when I then try to type in the field, I get the error message that the element is covered.

When I try to assert that the overlay is not there anymore and add

```js
cy.get('.blockUI blockOverlay').should('not.exist')
```

Cypress also passes the assertion even though the element does exist and covers the other element and `cy.get('#lead_name').type('foo')` fails.

Is there any way to address this problem like

```js
//This does not work it's just a sample to explain what I want to do
//test if the element I want to get is not covered
cy.get('#lead_name').should('not.be.covered')
//or test if the element is actionable
cy.get('#lead_name').should('be.actionable')
```

to make sure it waits until the form has loaded?

{edit} This is the error message I get from Cypress:

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.type() failed because this element:

<input name="CrmLead[first_name]" id="CrmLead_first_name" type="text" maxlength="255">

is being covered by another element:

<div class="blockUI blockOverlay" style="z-index: 1000; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 665px; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.9; cursor: wait; position: absolute;"></div>
```

{edit 2} This is the code I use, condensed to the relevant parts:

```js
it('should select new lead', () {
cy.visit(Cypress.env('lead_url'))
cy.get('#new_lead).click() //this opens the new form which takes some time to load
cy.get('#lead_name').type('foo')
cy.get('#lead_last_name').type('bar')
cy.get('.button').click()
}
```

{edit 3} The more I test possible solutions, the more I become convinced that the problem is not the overlay, but something in the Cypress code itself.

When I open the form manually it never takes more than a second for the loading spinner to disappear, usually just 0.1-0.2 seconds.

Yet when Cypress opens the form the form just doesn't load properly as the loading spinner stays there indefinitely.

Comment: Could you provide a full example code that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: The complete code is pretty long and uses POM, but I added the relevant part of the code to my OP

Comment: Unfortunately I can not give you a link to the app itself as it is private :(

Comment: I think you can change the state of the element with `.invoke('show')`. Here is a short video explaining how you can do this. https://testautomationu.applitools.com/advanced-cypress-tutorial/chapter4.html

Comment: Thanks. Tried this and while the command ```cy.get('#lead_portlet').invoke('show')```triggers as intended, it does not change the fact that it's being covered by the Overlay :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The checking of the overlay should be done in two steps.

```js
cy.get('.blockUI.blockOverlay')
  .should('exist')
  .then($overlay => $overlay.remove()) 
cy.get('.blockUI.blockOverlay').should('not.exist')

cy.get('#lead_name', {timeout: 10000})
.should(($el) => {                    // should will cause retry
  return Cypress.dom.isFocusable($el) // instead of visible, more relevent to actionability
})
```

It's possible if you just do the second step, Cypress passes that command ***before*** the overlay is present.

It's the same principle as checjing a loading spinner, which has be tackled on SO before.

BTW you are selecting an element with two classed (according to the error message), so you need two `.` in the selector.

Perhaps that's the only change you need!

---

I added another check above that might help. `Cypress.dom.isFocusable`.

From the docs [Is focusable](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/dom#Is-focusable)

> Cypress internally uses this method everywhere to figure out whether an element is hidden, mostly for actionability.

---

If you get really stuck, take a look at Gleb Bahmutov's walkthrough video here [Debug the Element Visibility Problems in Cypress](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/debug-visibility/)

---

One more idea - you can try removing the covering overlay in the test - added a line to the sample above.

Comment: First of all, yes. I made an extremely stupid mistake. ```cy.get('.blockUI.blockOverlay').should('exist')``` is of course the correct syntax.

Comment: Yet this solution still does not seem to work as ```cy.get('.blockUI.blockOverlay').should('not.exist')``` simply causes the test to fail when the Overlay is still there

```Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected <div.blockUI.blockOverlay> not to exist in the DOM, but it was continuously found```

Comment: Does the overlay go away when the form settles? (In the browser, not in the test)

Comment: Yes, it goes away when the form settles, usually this takes <<1 second. But for some reason it takes much longer when I open it in Cypress

Comment: There is also a loading spinner present while the form is loading. I will look into that as well now

Comment: That's a head-scratcher indeed. What is the app framework?

Comment: The framework is Yii v1.1.6

Comment: By now I am pretty much convinced that I need to address the underlying problem instead of the Overlay: *Why is Cypress loading the form breaking the page?*

Comment: Maybe compare the network calls between Browser/Cypress - is one not completing?

Comment: The network calls are all going through

Comment: I marked your answer as solution, because I really think that it would solve the original problem. However after diving deeper and deeper I am convinced that my problem is something else that doesn't have to do with my original question. But the answers in this question might still be helpful for someone with a similar problem!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{force: true}` with `type()`. This will igonre the overlapping of other element.

```js
cy.get('#lead_name').type('foo', {force: true})
```

Or if you want to assert that the element has `opacity 0.9` you can use:

```js
cy.get('.blockUI blockOverlay')
  .should('have.attr', 'style')
  .and('include', 'opacity: 0.9')
```

Or, you can wait for the element to not have the opacity, in that case you can use:

```js
cy.get('.blockUI blockOverlay', {timeout: 7000})
  .should('have.attr', 'style')
  .and('not.include', 'opacity: 0.9')
```

Comment: I have been thinking about this as well. It's kinda the last resort as I would prefer to have the form load completely before I start testing

Comment: So after the form complete load, the covering part is gone ?

Comment: Yes, if I wait until the form has loaded the covering part is gone. It's just an semi-opaque overlay that is used to make sure people don't start typing in it before it is fully loaded

Comment: It looks like adding {force:true} does not help as the input gets deleted again once the form is fully loaded. So I need a way to make sure the form has loaded (and the overlay is gone) before I start typing in it

Comment: You can do something this, you can check that the element doesn't have the opacity and you can give a timeout, so that cypress waits till the timeout value to make sure the element doesn't have opacity. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes this definitely works, if the overlay appears long enough. Yet, in the case that the loading time is extremely short, the test fails when trying to ```cy.get('.blockUI blockOverlay', {timeout: 7000})
  .should('have.attr', 'style').and('not.include', 'opacity: 0.9')``` as it can not find the element anymore. This is some crazy stuff here :(

Comment: I know this sounds crazy, but when I add the assertion ```cy.get('.blockUI blockOverlay', {timeout: 7000})   .should('have.attr', 'style').and('not.include', 'opacity: 0.9')``` the loading time is milliseconds and it can't find the overlay. Yet when I exchange it with ```cy.wait('20000')``` the loading time suddenly becomes infinite.

Comment: It gets weirder: ```Timed out retrying after 7000ms: expected 'z-index: 1000; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 665px; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.9; cursor: wait; position: absolute;' to not include 'opacity: 0.9'```It says right in the error message that it contains opacity 0.9

Comment: `cy.wait('20000')` will wait for 20 seconds, it is also waiting in milliseconds. But please avoid using cy.wait, it will bring flakiness. Also it seems like even after 7000 milliseconds the opacity is not removed, which is mentioned correctly in your error message. have you tried increasing the timeout from 7000 to 9000?

Comment: Yes, it seems there is some strange behaviour of Cypress at the works. In fact the Overlay/Loading spinner does not disappear at all when I open the form in Cypress. Something causes the page to freeze. This is weird as this never happens when I use the site manually

Comment: I marked the question as resolved as by now the original question doesn't seem to be my main problem. I will have to dive much deeper to find the reason for this behaviour. Yet I am sure that your answer can help other with a similar problem to my original question!